# Entering Text From Delphi To Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2 and use the following code to enter the letter Y into a bookmark in a Word (2010) template.

```
Doc.Bookmarks.Item('NS').Range.InsertAfter('Y');
```

Except in the document, instead of the letter Y, the number 89 appears.

Is the fault likely to be from my code or in the Word document? Any direction gratefully received.

Comment: What happens when you manually add the character after the bookmark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your literal `'Y'` is a character literal rather than a string string literal. The [ASCII code for `Y` is 89](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

So, you are passing a `Char` rather than a `string`. When Word needs to get a string representation of that integer it simply converts the integer `89` to its textual representation, the string `'89'`.

To get around the problem you can do this:

```
var
  Text: string;
....
Text := 'Y';
Doc.Bookmarks.Item('NS').Range.InsertAfter(Text);
```

The idea is that we ensure that we pass a string to `InsertAfter()` rather than a character. Remember that `InsertAfter()` receives a variant parameter and so you do need to be careful about the type of the payload stored in the variant.

Comment: A typecast to string might work as well: `InsertAfter(string('Y'))`.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. My original answer had that but I prefer this more explicit version for the purpose of exposition.

Comment: Hmm. Makes you wonder. If I create a `procedure X(V: OleVariant);` then VarType(V) will return 8 (varOleStr) always, no matter if I use the constant, the cast or a string variable as input.

Comment: This solved it in one, so thank you very much! I'm the new boy here, so is there anything it is good manners to do - any credits to give or that kind of thing?

Comment: Upvoting good answers and accepting the one that answered the question the best.

Comment: @GolezTrol Perhaps this is late binding. Perhaps that makes a differences. Given that ASCII 89 is Y, there's really no other explanation is there?!

Comment: Yes, it's obvious that Word interprets the input as a Char (or even a Byte/ordinal). Clearly your solution works, but it leaves me curious of why this happens.